# C: typedef struct. Function doesn't recognize type of struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

So the situation is...
I have three files: main.c | functions.h | functions.c

In main.c I created a struct, and defined it as a new type called "score":

```
typedef struct
{
    int iWins = 0, iWins2 = 0, iTies = 0;
} score;
```

I then created an instance of "score", called `SpScore`:

```
score SpScore;
```

I passed it to a function (in main.c) called `spgame_f`:

```
spgame_f(SpScore);
```

`spgame_f` is located in functions.c. Now when compiling it gives me the error:

```
unknown type name: score
```

I have also tried defining the struct at the top of "functions.c", which gave me the error:

```
expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token" (error for the line where the integer's are declared in the struct).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't initialize the fields of a struct in the definition of the type, because it's prohibited, since it doesn't make sense.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks fundamental understanding of the language being used.

Comment: Your question shows three isolated code snippets. It's hard to tell how they relate to each other, and you haven't shown us the declaration or definition of the function you're calling. Suggested reading: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot initialize `struct` members in a `typedef`, it doesn't make sense. You should do like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    // No = 0 here
    int iWins, iWins2, iTies;
} score;

int main() {
    // Initializing to 0 here
    score SpScore = {0,0,0};
}
```

Also, you should put the `typedef` inside a `.h` header file and include it in all the `.c`/`.h` files making use of that definition, or you will get a "unknown type..." error:

## score.h

```
#ifndef __SCORE_H__
#define __SCORE_H__

typedef struct
{
    // No = 0 here
    int iWins, iWins2, iTies;
} score;

#endif
```

And:

## main.c etc.

```
#include "score.h"

int main() {
    score pScore = {0,0,0};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, but my problem is still there :/

Comment: Please, take a moment to get a good book and study C. It's very easy to get a basic-intermediate knowledge of C, but you have to _learn_ it, don't hammer your statements the hard way until you get something that compiles.

Comment: Well I have read a book on C and have watched a few courses and tutorial series, I'm just having this problem :)

Comment: I've edited the answer with some more context. Keep on learning! And get a _better_ C book (or study harder), this topic should be covered.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to fix the problem now anyway :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm new to this ^^